# how to pass parameters between controllers (hidden in url) -mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, controller

my first actioncontroller is:

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Authentication",new {code = result });
```

and i use the "result" parameter in diffrent controller. like

```
  public ActionResult Index(string code)
        {
            ...
            TempData["valcode"] = code;

            return View();
        }



 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AuthenticateUser(string validationcode)
        {
            if (validationcode == TempData["valcode"].ToString())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
          ...
            }
        }
```

it works fine but in url, i see the code value. (http://www.test.com/Authentication/code=123)
i dont want code value to be seen in url

how can i hide it from url? (besides encrypting)

Comment: You cant. Your controller method is not psychic. If you do not pass the value, then the controller cannot receive it. You can always use `TempData` but that only lasts one request and would be lost if the user refreshed the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Using Sessions to pass data between controllers.

```
Session["valcode"] = code;
```

But note that,  using sessions to pass data between controllers is a bad idea because it will 
 use the app pool of the application which will eventually slow down the application.
If using sessions is mandatory, make sure you destroy session variables after being used.

Hope this helps.